# Unity 3d Check Collision at specific Point

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out how to get the point where two game objects collide in the event of a collision. I have walls that I can place. It recognizes that it collides with the placed object, only I want that if the edges collide it is not taken as a collision.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add colliders to objects that detect collisions, such as: Box Collider, capsule Collider, Sphere Collider, etc. Then write a script, you only need to hang the script on the detected object, instead of hanging the detection script on the game character, reducing the role of the load of the mount script

Answer (score 0):

When objects collide, the physical material determines how the collider interacts with other objects (collision behavior). The physical material is used in conjunction with the collision box
Project window->right click->Create->Physic Material
[image]
[image]
[image]
Change rebound to 1
[image]
Drag this physical material to the two cubes and the effect is as follows
[image]
【Collision detection function】

```
     public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {
        //When the script is mounted on an object that satisfiesthe 
    necessary conditions for collision
        //When a collision occurs, this function will be called
        void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
             DEbug.Log("collision occurs")
         //For example, to deal with colliding with an object to generate special effects
        }

        //When the collision ends, this function will be called automatically
        void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
       {
          Debug.Log("end of collision")
       }

      //This function will be called automatically in collision
     void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
    {
         Debug.Log("collision (contact)")
    }
 }
```

Mount this Test script to one of the two objects
[image]
At runtime, when a collision occurs, the corresponding function will be automatically called for logical processing
[image]
Ability to detect different stages of collision generation through code
【trigger】
Allows objects mounted with rigid bodies to penetrate the collision box (an arrow through the heart)
main effect
No physical effects are produced, only collision detection is performed, and the corresponding logic is processed through the response function

[image]

Making a trigger is very simple, just check the Is Trigger property of the collision box on the object with the rigid body on the object that meets the necessary conditions for collision generation

[image]

【Trigger detection function】

```
   public class Test : MonoBehaviour
   {
    //unless this function is automatically called when sending
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision){
      Debug.Log("trigger occurs");
      //You can get GameObject directly through Collider
       Degug.Log(collision.gameObject.name);
    }

   //When the trigger ends, the function will be called automatically
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider collision){
    Debug.Log("trigger end");
    }

    // This function will be called automatically when triggered
     void OnTriggerStay(Collider collision){
          Debug.Log("penetrating (contacting)")
      }
  }
```

Mount this Test script to an object with a rigid body

[image]

At runtime, when a trigger is generated, the corresponding function will be automatically called for logical processing

[image]

Ability to detect different stages of trigger generation through code

The most important contents are the necessary conditions for collision generation, the core parameters on rigid body and collision box components, and the 6 functions for collision and trigger detection